# CSS Table alignment issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-tables

I'm working on a table here using a combination of Bootstrap + manual CSS.

http://rgmgstandings.tk/

For some reason the second table is aligned slighty to the right.

Can someone inspect the page and explain to me why this is happening?

Heres the CSS I've used if needed:

```
<style>
body {
    font-family:'VERDANA', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:125%;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {background: #FFFFFF}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #ECECEC}


table.table-condensed td.team {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
}

table.table-condensed th.team {
    text-align: left;
}

tr.top {
    background: #666666;
    color: white;
}

th.pts {
    background: #F3F3F3;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

.table>tbody>tr>td {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

td.pts {
    background: #F3F3F3;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

th.otl {
    width: 6%;
}

td.otl {
    text-align: center;
}

table.table-condensed td {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

table.table-condensed th {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

td.rank {
    width: 5px;
}

.table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>thead>tr>th {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

</style>
```

Comment: your thing you `container` class has a `padding` and your structure is `.container` inside `.container` so remove the inside `.container` outside level of the first `.container`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place the inner container(red box) outside the parent container(blue box). they must be on the same hierarchy

[image]

They should look like this:

[image]

Comment: THANKS! Such a silly mistake on my part. Upvoting as soon the the timer goes down :)

Comment: Dyrandz answer is right, but if you don't want to move the Div, then you can override Bootstrap css by adding a style  <div class="container" style="padding-left:0">